# Show a textbox if a hidden field contains correct value

Tags: jquery

I am working on a form that requires a login and when the login is correct a set of fields with data from the query is pre-filled. On one of the fields I need to have a condition met. If the state abbreviation is MO id need for a textbox input to appear if not MO it does. I have googled this for two days with no luck. The hidden field is called stuff. I can make it work onclick but I can't seem to get it on page load. I appreciate any help.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#wordingSpine').hide(); //hide field on start

    $('#stuff').change(function() {

     var $index = $('#stuff').index(this);

     if($('#stuff').val() != 'MO') { //if this value is NOT selected
     $('#wordingSpine').hide(); //this field is hidden
     } 
     else {
     $('#wordingSpine').show();//else it is shown

     }
        });
 });
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

By the sounds of it, you just need to trigger the change event when the dom is ready:

```
$('#stuff').on('change', function() {
  $('#wordingSpine').toggle(this.value == 'MO');
}).trigger('change');
```

**[.trigger()](http://api.jquery.com/trigger/)**

Comment: Thanks for you help. I am not really a coder and syntax is a problem for me so I am not sure where to insert the code you provided. Does it replace something in my code or does it replace the whole thing. THANKS!